# Trunk Release Malfunction

Tags: battery, mini-cooper, trunk

2003 Mini Cooper
The battery is dead so the key fob and toggle switch on the dash don't unlock the trunk.  I pulled on the release ring under the back seat, but it only partially releases the trunk, not enough to get it open.  Now how do I open the trunk so that I can charge the battery?

Comment: That release cable is supposed to open the hatch.  I'm guessing that there is a problem with the mechanism likely due to disuse.  You might try wiggling it a bit.  Otherwise, how about connecting an external 12V source under the hood and seeing if you can release the hatch normally?

Answer (score 1):

MINI thought this might be a problem so gave you a positive post up front to apply power to. To find it, pop the hood (bonnet) and look for it near the left side of the engine compartment near the cowl area (sort of under the overhang), by the strut tower. It should look like this:

[image]

(Image taken from [this video](https://youtu.be/c1TQF_RJSKY).)

Whether charging your system or jumping it, apply the positive (+) side to this post, then put the negative side to an exposed grounding point (if jumping, use the standard method to attach your connections). This should give you enough power to use the fob to open the trunk (boot/rear hatch/whatever you'd like to call it). You can then either jump the battery directly or charge it. You could also leave it in place here to charge or jump as well. Whatever you'd prefer. Just be careful to disconnect the negative side first so you don't inadvertently cause a short and fry the charging system on the donor car (if you are jumping it). It wouldn't be pretty.